# Code for therefore symbol?

Tags: symbols, amsmath

I just learned in math class that the therefore symbol is three dots in a triangle like this: [image: therefore symbol]

How do I do this in LaTeX, and what is the code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out, the code is `\therefore`. So like this:

[image: $\therefore x = \pm 3$]

Comment: Yeah, it probably should.

Comment: I added a better example image to the question.